# How do I add a new WPF UserControl to my .NetCore 3.1 application?

Tags: wpf, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

How do I create a WPF UserControl using .Net Core 3.1 in Visual Studio 2019?
I looked through the default templates available in "Add .. New .. Dialog," but I don't seem to see it.

Am I missing something?
Do I need to add it from a the command line?

I've got the DevExpress WPF/.Net Core packages installed and can add a DevExpress flavoured UserControl.
I'm able to create/add one of those from the installed templates.

How do I do so in vanilla .NetCore/WPF

Thanks,JohhB

Comment: You create a UserControl as usual: Open the context menu on the project, select `Add -> UserControl (WPF)...` or `Add -> New Item... -> UserControl (WPF)`

Comment: @Clemens - UserControl does not show up in my Right Mouse Context menu, nor does it show up in my list of available templates in Add .. New -->.  This is odd, because I can "Create a New Project" as a .NetCore User Control; can't see how to add one to an existing .NetCore WPF project. Thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps it is not a WPF project, no idea.

Answer (score -2):

Same as WinForms...compile your code, open Toolbox, drag it from there onto either your designer page or into the XAML code directly.

Comment: A WPF <UserControl> is not available as options from toolbox. It is @ the same level as <Window>

Comment: Hang on, I'm confused. UserControls are meant to be subclasssed, once you do that *then* you see your control appear inToolbox. Are you trying to add an instance of the base UserControl itself to your window? If so.....umm....why?!